# Tweeting a message using Swift and Parse

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, twitter, parse-platform

I'm currently writing a social networking app for iOS using Swift and the Parse SDK. My app is basically a UITableView that displays a timeline of messages from users that sign up for my app. But there is one part that I'm struggling with that I hope the community will be able to help me solve.

My problem is that when I want to be able to tweet the message that the user to my twitter followers. But I cant seem to figure out how to get message displayed in my timeline as the text for my tweet share sheet using the Social Framework built into iOS.  I also have a Alert to be displayed when the user taps on a message to give a list of sharing options. I figure this alert is not the cause my issue. I will attach my source code for my TimelineTableViewController. Full code examples on how to active this logic in Swift is very helpful.

[TimelineTableViewController](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3bn62_z-uzZRVBFQ2FlTUJDd2s/view?usp=sharing)